# Why it works in nodejs or any other javascript compiler?

Tags: javascript

I was testing the filter function for an array of objects, but by mistake I defined **b** as an array of numbers, so I decided to see if the filter function gives me an error if I accessed an invalid property, but unexpectedly it works, and i don't know why, could someone explain to me why it works?

```
a = {a:5};
b = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(b.filter(x => x.z === a.a.z).pop()); // 5
```

Comment: `console.log(a.a.z)`

Comment: `5.z` is a SyntaxError, but `let x = 5; let y = x.z;` is valid, and `y` has the value undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.a` is `5`. `a.a.z` is `undefined`.

`x` is always a number. `x.z` is `undefined`.

`undefined === undefined`

The filter copies all the values in the array.

Pop pulls the last value off the array. It is 5.